# Do mi and mío have different connotations?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, connotaciones, posesivos

I usually use the possessives `mi` and `mío` interchangeably.

**For example:**

> - Esta es la casa mía.
> - Esta es mi casa.

However, do the two have different connotations? (e.g. is one more formal or used more in certain regions?)

In this case I used `mi` and `mía` as examples, but this would also apply to `su` vs. `suyo`, `tu`, vs. `tuyo`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Esta es la casa mía" may be correct, but I've never heard it from the lips of any native Spanish speaker. We always say "esta es mi casa".

We use the form "mía":

- If someone asks "¿de quién es esa casa?", and you answer "mía", or "es mía".
- In sentences like "ese es tu vaso y este, el mío".
- (In many other cases.)

Comment: You're from Spain?  Maybe it's a regional thing.  I frequently heard "la mía" or "el mío" as a standard idiom when I was in Argentina.

Comment: Yes, I'm from Spain. Here, we do say "esta es la mía", but I've never heard "esta es la casa mía". Maybe they say it, in other countries.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer (I'm from Spain too)

Comment: Another spanish here agreeing this answer. Maybe the sentence "es la casa mía" comes from a region of South America. But it sounds to me like Italian, not Spanish.

Comment: @luke It’s super-duper more common to say “Ésta as mi casa”, but there is room for saying “Ésta es casa mía” (without the *la*, however).  See my answer for the difference between *mi casa* and *casa mía*.

Comment: @tchrist I have heard and seen phrases like "la mano mía" and "el sistema nuestro." What would be the explanation for this?

Answer (score 4):

From your examples:

> Esta casa es mía.
>
> Esta es mi casa.

The meaning is the same. I would say that example 1.) emphasizes more who does the house belong to. Pretty much like `my` and `mine`, I believe?

I would use 2.) in a more casual way, something like `Look! This is my house` whereas 1.) is more for `This is mr. Smith's house, that is mrs. Robinson's, but next house is mine.`

Comment: As simple as: `Esta casa es mía = This house is mine` and `Esta es mi casa = This is my house`

Answer (score 1):

The short story is that in this case, “mi casa” means just plain “my house”, whereas “casa mía” means ***“my*** house”.  Hear the difference?  In the second one, you say the word *my* with more emphasis, as though it were set in italic.

It’s super-duper more common to say “Ésta es mi casa”, but there *is* room for saying “Ésta es casa mía” (without the *la*). You might conceivably do that if somebody just said to you that that one was *their* house.

The stressed construction with *mía* at the end is the equivalent of leaning on the word in English, like saying “Yeah, well, this one is ***my*** house.”

See? That one would be *casa mía* instead of just *mi casa*.

You’ll find that Spanish will often simply invert normal word order for places where English more often uses stressed words alone. Inversion here would stress the ***my*** part.  Sure, you wouldn’t normally do that, but on rare occasion, you just might.

Comment: When would you use "ésta es casa mía"?

Comment: @JoulSauron Pretty only the sort of thing that would be as a response to somebody else first saying “Ésta es mi casa,” because you’re trying to contrast with theirs.  It’s when in English you would say “And this one is ***my*** house” (as opposed to that other one being theirs).  Or if you were translating "this house of mine".

Comment: *casa mia* is seldom used. If you want to stress the fact that it's **your** house, you usually say **mi** casa (stressing the "mi").

Comment: @tchrist I have never heard "ésta es casa mía" in Spain, not it daily use nor in literature. Probably a couple of centuries ago or before, but never nowadays. We only say "esta casa es mía" or "ésta es mi casa".

Comment: @JoulSauron Yes, that sounds more natural.  I was just trying to explain to Luke the general difference between “mi cosa” and “cosa mía”, for arbitrary cosas. :)  I wouldn’t consider “mi amigo” interchangeable with “amigo mío” either, although the difference isn’t easily translated into English.